# Excel does pallet X in location Y physically match the system

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I'm trying to physically validate pallet id's and locations compared to what our system indicates. There are two tables, one is exported data listing location and pallet id. The sheet with exported data looks similar to this:

```
LOCATION    PALLETID

1WS0101AB   123456
1WS0512CF   543524
1ES2319DF   843052
1WS4529BF   659104
```

The other sheet is a physical scan of the location and pallet id. The formula to validate if the location and pallet id match is:

```
=IF(AND(A2=0,B2=0),"",IF(NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Pallets_By_Row,1,FALSE)=B2)),"FOUND","NOT LISTED"))
```

The problem is it's only validating if the pallet id is found. I need something to verify that when location Y physically has pallet X in it, that excel shows FOUND if the system export data agrees. If the system exported data disagrees, then I get an ERROR response.

Comment: countifs should be able to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, COUNTIFS() can do this for you. Here is a formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(Exported_Location, Check_Location, Exported_PalletID, Check_PalletID)>0, "FOUND", "NOT LISTED")
```

- `Exported_Location` is the column of locations in your exported spreadsheet
- `Check_Location` is the listed location of the pallet you're checking
- `Exported_PalletID` is the column of palletIDs in your exported spreadsheet
- `Check_PalletID` is the palletID of the pallet you're checking

`COUNTIFS` will count the number if instances when both of those conditions are `TRUE`. So if there is an entry in the exported spreadsheet with an exactly matching Location and PalletID, it will return `1`, and the cell will say `FOUND`.

I used FormulaChop to generate the formula above. (Full Disclosure: I wrote FormulaChop). [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfAME.png) is a link to a screenshot of its output. [Here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=05074654861998377429) is a link to a sample spreadsheet that implements the formula above.